# How do i install Perl 5.10.1 on Debian, using the packaging system?

Tags: debian, perl

I have little to no idea about administrating Debian, but I would like to at least use that release of Perl. Googling has proven unfruitful, so i turn to you, Stackoverflow.

Note: Managed to find the solution already, this explains how to enable installs of 'testing': http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

Comment: $ apt-cache policy perl

perl:
  Installed: 5.10.1-11
  Candidate: 5.10.1-11
  Version table:
 *** 5.10.1-11 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org unstable/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install perl

Comment: I think that installs Perl v5.10.0

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful not to mess with the system `perl`. Instead, I would recommend installing [Perl 5.10.1 from source](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/INSTALL) in a custom location. E.g.:

```
sh Configure -Dprefix=/opt/perl
```

Comment: @mithaldu Thank you for accepting my answer. It is customary to vote up the answer you accept.

Comment: I like Debian's Perl.  It is nice to be able to install non-CPAN modules and have them work (Audio::XMMSClient, for example).  Any modules that I can install from CPAN, I do, and store them in ~/perl5 with local::lib.  Maintaining your own Perl is a pain in the ass.  Let your OS do it for you.

Comment: Yeah, don't mess with the system perl. You will break your whole system. If you want a different version, install it manually and separately. You could still use checkinstall if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo aptitude install perl`? to search for the packages you want do `sudo aptitde search KEYWORD`.

Comment: I think that installs Perl v5.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Debian uses Perl as a dependency for many of its applications so its not wise to mess with the installed version of Perl.
If you would like to try out your code with a different verion of Perl like 5.10 then you should install perlbrew. It allows you to test your code against multiple versions of perl by having multiple perl installations on the same system in a easy to manage way. 
http://perlbrew.pl/

You can install perlbrew from debian repository

```
sudo apt-get install perlbrew
```

Once you have installed Perlbrew you can manage your Perl versions easily.
following commands install Perl 5.16.0 and switch your active Perl version to 5.16.0

```
perlbrew install perl-5.16.0

perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
```

Then you can run your scripts using the Perlbrew command

```
perlbrew exec perl myprogram.pl
```

HTH